# Reactjs, is it possible to render only 1 of the same component?

Tags: reactjs

I rewrite the question to be more clear now:
ComponentA will have a callback from the websocket, and it will decode the data from websocket and see which ComponentB (1 of the 50) will be updated to draw something on it. And the websocket will update may be in 100ms, so i don't want 1 of the ComponentB update will make other 49 componentB to rerender. What could i do to solve this problem? Thanks

```
export default function ComponentA(props) {

    const [data, setData] = React.useState('red');
    
    //call back from websocket, using @anephenix/sarus
    function callBackFromWebsocket(jsonData)
    {
        //This will update one of the ComponentB depended on the json in the websocket
        //This will be update very quick , may be 100ms per time.
        
        setData(decoded json Data for ComponentB id = ??);
    }
    
    //...Sarus connect websocket code and set the websocket message to callBackFromWebsocket
    
    return (
        <ComponentB id="1" data={data}/>
        <ComponentB id="2" data={data}/>
        <ComponentB id="3" data={data}/>            
        ..
        <ComponentB id="50" data={data}/>
    )
}

export default function ComponentB(props) {

    useEffect(()=>{
        
        //Do something on the props.data.
    
    }, [props.data]);

    return (
        ...Some UI component based on the props.data.
    )
}
```

Comment: Please add complete code.

Comment: what is logic behind id="2", id !== data ??

Comment: if i understand correctly, you are calling component B inside component A, so a change in state of A , will re render component B. If you want to limit those re render, then move B out of A

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are many approaches to handle such a problem.

One is to provide different data to each component.

Something like

```
// ComponentA:
export default function ComponentA(props) {
  const initialColor = 'red';
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(initialColor);
  return (
    <>
      <ComponentB id="1" color={initialColor} />
      <ComponentB id="2" color={data} />
      <Button onClick={() => setData('yellow')} />
    </>
  );
}
```

---

Another would be to add logic to the ComponentB on whether it should be "updateable"

```
// ComponentA:
export default function ComponentA(props) {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState('red');
  return (
    <>
      <ComponentB id="1" color={data} noUpdate />
      <ComponentB id="2" color={data} />
      <Button onClick={() => setData('yellow')} />
    </>
  );
}

// Component B:
export default function ComponentB(props) {
  const [color, setColor] = useState(props.color);
  console.log('Refresh');

  useEffect(() => {
   if (!props.noUpdate) {
     setColor(props.color);
   }
  }, [props.color]);

  return (
    <button style={backgroundColor: color} />
  )
}
```

Comment: Actually, it is update will sometime on id=1, sometime on id=2, and in my real case, there are 50 (id from 1 to 50) same ComponentB on ComponentA, and the update on which id is calculated in realtime. So your first method may not work, for your second approach, if i check if it is need to update or not in the ComponentB, then all 50 ComponentB will need to render 1 time, i want ComponentA only update the specified ComponentB, not to check in the ComponentB to make it render even it is not needed. And the update is very quick, may be 200 msec per update on 1 of the ComponentB.

Comment: @ChiFaiWong then you will have to post a more "real" code sample, along with some sort of how you decide on whether a component should update or not. Also are you interested on if it will update or do you care about skipping the actual re-render of a component ?